# How to make uploaded file permanent to node without node submit

Tags: 7, nodes, forms, media, files

My module automatically save new empty node when user create new node and redirect to edit this node. Now, is it possible to make uploaded file on _node_edit form without submitting form?

edit:
When user visit "node/add/article" for example, my module save new node type article and redirect user to "node/NID/edit" to edit this node. In node have fields type "image" and "file". User upload image and file. 
Now, how to alter their (ajaxified) upload process to make this files permanent to node without click on "Save" button on node edit form?

Comment: Do you mean you want the programatically created node to have a file already on it when they get to the second edit form?

Comment: Not exactly, I added more explanation in the question.

Comment: Why not actually save the file to the node when you save the empty node? Is that an option?

Comment: no, the user chooses what to upload. The main idea is to ajaxify node edit form (saving each field data when focusout for example) - other input types like text and select are ready, but file upload not

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [autosave](http://drupal.org/project/autosave) module, which allows automatic saving of the node form via ajax while the user is editing the form.

If it doesn't do exactly what you are after it would be a great place to look for ideas on how to code it yourself.

Probably if it doesn't do exactly what you want the easiest path might be to make a patch for that module to add what you need, instead of writing something from scratch.

Comment: Yes, it looked before I made ​​my decision - it is far from my needs, thanks anyway. The question is still ...